# scrollView and footer issue in android

Tags: android, scrollview

In my Android application I am using a header and a footer. In between I have a table inside a scrollview.
The problem is that I am not able to see the footer even if I am adding it the same as header, using `include` tag.
If I set the height and width of the scrollview to some specified length it works fine, but again, when it changes the orientation it doesn't.

Could any one let me know how I can make my footer visible at the bottom of the screen without changing the scrollview height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose root view is `LinearLayout`. If so then make sure to set following attributes of the middle `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView ... 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    ...
</ScrollView
```

Answer (score 1):

Your footer should have `android:layout_marginTop="-95sp"`
and your scroll view should have `android:layout_marginBottom="95sp"`

Change the number (95) to the size of the footer.